# Cannot weight paint Geometry Node primitives

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting

I'm diving into geometry nodes today using 3.1 Alpha.

At this point I used *Distribute Points on Faces* and connected the *Density Factor* to a vertex group so I can use Weight Paint to change the value. But, here is the problem: my object will stay blue - the weight paint does not effect my object.

Part of the problem I solved already: I bypassed the *Group Input's* *Geometry-node* and used a Curve Primitive. During the Weight Paint I tried somethings and I see it only would paint the 'original' Geometry and not the geometry made from this Curve Primitive.

How can I make this work? Is there a node so I can 'convert' this into a geometry I can paint on? I attached a simplified illustration of my problem.

[image: Weight Paint doesnt work on Geometry Node]

Answer (score 2):

Since you join an object to a primitive that doesn't have vertex groups, it isn't saved. Change the order:

[image]

Comment: Ah this is interesting, didn't know that there was a sequence in a the join geometry node. But, still the primitive isn't weight paintable

Comment: Of course, because it doesn't exist in mesh data. All that you edit comes from group input before GN is appled. Apply modifier as quellenform suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The geometry created using Geometry Nodes is not editable as a mesh until you apply the modifier.

To do this, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Apply all Modifiers* (or do this explicitly in the properties if you only want to apply one modifier as shown below).

Only then is the geometry available as a mesh and can be edited as usual.

[image]

Comment: But that diminishes the whole point of using geomtry nodes, right? I'm looking for a non-destructive way

Comment: @jspr Yes and No. Geometry nodes are still a bit new, and in some respects harmonize relatively poorly with the usual destructive workflow. The problem here in Blender is that a non-destructive workflow cannot be seamlessly combined with a destructive workflow. If you really want to have everything completely procedural, I would take a closer look at [Houdini](https://www.sidefx.com/).